# How to convert 2-dimensional double array from 2-dimensional Integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, casting, primitive-types

I am trying to create a utility function to create a 2-dimensional array of doubles out of a 2-dimensional array of Integers (which is created from deeplearning4j's KerasTokenizer's textsToSequences(String[] texts) method). I created the method below but keep getting `NullPointerExceptions` at line 111 (`doubles[i][j] = list.get(j);`). How can I change my method or create a new one to fix this problem?

```
public static double[][] integerToDoubleArray(Integer[][] integers) {
        double[][] doubles = new double[integers.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(integers[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                doubles[i][j] = list.get(j);
            }
        }
        return doubles;
    }
```

I call it using the following method with the following API: https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/nn/modelimport/keras/preprocessing/text/KerasTokenizer.html#textsToSequences-java.lang.String:A-

```
private static double[][] encodeSequences(KerasTokenizer tokenizer, int length, ArrayList<String> sentences) {
        return integerToDoubleArray(tokenizer.textsToSequences(arraylistToArray(sentences)));
    }
```

Comment: Are there `null`s inside `integers`?

Comment: can you put how do you call your method ?

Comment: @luk2302 The issue is actually that each element of `doubles` was not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the second dimension of `doubles` (which is an array of double arrays), nor did you initialize each element of it, so you are getting this exception. Just initialize each row to a new double array with the length of the integer array at that index.

```
public static double[][] integerToDoubleArray(Integer[][] integers) {
    double[][] doubles = new double[integers.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        doubles[i] = new double[integers[i].length];
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(integers[i]);
        System.out.println(list);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            doubles[i][j] = list.get(j);
        }
    }
    return doubles;
}
```

It should be noted that you do not need to convert each row of the two dimensional Integer array to a `List`, as you can simply use `integers[i][j]` to access the element at row `i` and column `j`. [Demo](https://ideone.com/UE5ZpU)

```
public static double[][] integerToDoubleArray(Integer[][] integers) {
    double[][] doubles = new double[integers.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        doubles[i] = new double[integers[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < integers[i].length; j++) {
            doubles[i][j] = integers[i][j];
        }
    }
    return doubles;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could solve your problem. I dont see any reason to use ArrayList during convertion.

```
public static double[][] integerToDoubleArray(Integer[][] integers) {
        
        //TODO: return empty double[][] array if integers 2-D array is empty
        
        double[][] doubles = new double[integers.length][integers[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < integers[0].length; j++) {
                doubles[i][j] = integers[i][j];

            }
        }
        return doubles;
    }
```